# How insisting on splitting long problems into small "elements" leads to overcompartmentalization

Tags: discussion

So the other day I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377250/scan-multi-rows-using-textscan-in-matlab/25378897#comment39611273_25378897) with a seemingly straight-forward solution. I expected the answer to be accepted and at most, to receive a comment asking for a clarification of something. However, what happened is that the OP's comment made me think they don't even know where the input data came from. So I decided to look around a bit...

What I discovered next, is that the OP had asked several related questions {see links below} that were "just the right amount" dissimilar to not be flagged as duplicate, and also didn't trigger the "wrath" of the community by presenting results (that actually were) obtained using code from previous answers as "attempts" by the OP that were close but "not quite" what they need.

See the following posts (partial list): [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277262/combine-several-string-into-one-string-in-matlab), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904965/draw-rectangle-based-on-data-in-matlab), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825221/store-same-length-content-to-one-variable-in-matlab), [post4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847559/sorting-multi-rows-from-a-file-using-matlab) <- this is actually a bit funny because **I** explained to the **same** OP the exact same thing he asked in his latest comment.

A critical coder will notice immediately that some of the solutions seem to be conflicting in the grand scheme of things (e.g. converting numbers to strings only to be converted back into numbers later), and will "stop everything" to ask the OP to explain the bigger picture, since what happens here is that a multitude of "best" solutions for very specific problems may not be the best solution overall.

I think that there's a certain *catch 22* here, where on the one hand, not mentioning the big picture may result in less or worse solutions (since the problem is somewhat ambiguous), but on the other hand, describing the big picture (in an incorrect fashion) may get the question closed for being too broad.

I obviously have nothing against this specific poster, and I'm assuming that I'm not the first to encounter "overcompartmentalization" and its faults.

And to my question: **How can we overcome overcompartmentalization?**

Answer (score 6):

I think this has nothing to do with breaking the question down to be fair. If you do it right you can use the SE model to get an answer to your question or to all your questions.
 I think it has to do with how the question is asked and possibly how the OP misunderstands the mechanism of Stack Overflow.

This has been said many times - Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service.

And even though the SE want us to avoid such terminology(*mainly not to scare people away*) the truth is that some people will just never learn what an actual question is and how to ask a good question properly.

For example, you are assigned a project and you have to do develop a program which reads xml files and populates a UI based on the data read. At this  point, you dont have a clue where to start .. what people seem to be doing here is they turn to Stack Overflow....

They will quickly realise that if they just copy-paste their assignment their question will get closed right away for being **too broad**. And that's the key here...

So they break things down but they can't do it properly. Sometimes (like in the example you have given) they get an optimal answer to the question they have asked but in the big picture -> next question -> next question it turns out they could have done it totally differently and achieve the same result. That's what asking separate questions and hardcore copy-pasting code does for ya...

So,

**How can we overcome overcompartmentalization?**

We can't. It's not our concern. It's completely down to the OP to break things down in a manner that  SE model is going to help him achieve the end result.

We should treat each question separately and we shouldn't have to screen through someones profile to see if they are "building" a piece of software using SO.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is unreasonable effort for the answerer to go to the asker's profile and look for related questions they previously asked in order to find crucial information that the OP themselves should provide.

This is why I suggest that the `Related\Similar` questions feed should prioritize **other questions by the same author** that have similar keywords in them.

Alternatively, and this applies mostly to multi-stage problems, it should be made clear that describing the bigger problem is not the same as asking a broad question, and askers shouldn't be discouraged to provide extra information when needed.

(I do not, however, consider it a good idea for a poster to provide a general "manifest" describing the problem, followed by a `Stage 3 of 5: <insert a sufficiently atomic question here>`)